# Codeigniter if URL segment is missing

Tags: php, security, function, codeigniter

Having found out that 3rd URL segments can be passed directly to the a function's parameter I did the following.

URL example:

> http://www.mysite.com/profile/user/64

Function in `profile` controller:

```
function user($user_id) //$user_id is 3rd URL segment
{
   //get data for user with id = $user_id
}
```

Using `$this->uri->segment(3)` returns FALSE is no segment exists. With the function parameter I get

> Missing argument 1

How can I return FALSE and not execute the function if the 3rd URL segment is missing? I'm looking for a simple solution without if statements, if possible.

Comment: Try `$this->uri->segment(2)`. I haven't used CodeIgniter, but I guess URI segment indices start at 0.

Comment: @wtp - CI segments start after index or if using htaccess to remove index after the domain (assuming CI index is in the root of the domian) and start counting from 1 so 3 is correct in this example. FYI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about default arguments:

```
function user($user_id = FALSE) //$user_id is 3rd URL segment
{
   //get data for user with id = $user_id
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So that should return FALSE before the query is executed? With codeigniter the 3rd segment is actually the user_id

Comment: You're right about segments. I was thinking of something else.

Comment: If the user_id is not defined, then it will default to FALSE. If it is defined, it will be that value instead.

Answer (score 4):

You get "Missing argument 1" because the function does not get the argument.

Try

```
function user(){
    if($this->uri->segment(3)){
        //get data for user with id = $this->uri->segment(3)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use this:

```
 public function user($id = null)
 {
   if(!isset($id))
     exit();

   // get data for user with id = $id
 }
```

or this

```
public function user()
{
  if( ! $this->uri->segment(3) )
    exit();

  // get data for user with id = $id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($this->uri->segment(3)) {
  return true
} else {
  return false
}
```